# for loop is not checking all the names

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am building a Book Blog App and I am trying to `get cleaned_data in creation form` and I am implementing a feature in which `"User can add multiple books (like tags) in blogpost which are saved in another model"` And `If any of book name (Book Tag) mentioned in the form not in the Book List` than It will show error `"You cannot create a new book name"`

So I made an `if else` statement to check if typed book name is in existing book in `Book Model` BUT Than it worked perfectly BUT The Problem occurred `When someone types 3 book names and one of them book name is in saved book name than , it will not see other book names which are not saved (It is saving the post), So it will not show error`

So I think I would access all the mentioned book names mentioned in form by **.all()** method  ( So it will check if any of book name is not in the existing names)  but this error is keep showing.

> 'list' object has no attribute 'all'

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    body = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    book_names = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='')

class Book(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    existing_book_names = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='')
```

views.py

```
def new_blog_post(request):
    ExistingNames = Book.objects.all().values_list('name', flat=True)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BlogForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            names = form.cleaned_data['book_names']
            new_post = form.save(commit=False)
            new_post.post_owner = request.user

            for inputTags in names.all():
                if inputTags in ExistingNames:
                    form.save()
                    return redirect('blogs')
                else:
                    messages.error(
                        request, 'You cannot add new name.')

    else:
        form = BlogForm()

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'new_blog_post.html', context)
```

I have tried many times but it didn't worked.

I will really appreciated your Help. Thank You

Comment: I think error is from this line `for inputTags in names.all()`. here `names` is already a list. so you don't need `.all` beside that. remove `.all` and it should work

Comment: Try to check this line `for inputTags in names.all()`. **names is not a django queryset** but a **list**. Instead do `for inputTags in names` and let us know the rest

Comment: I think the syntax for all() is wrong in itself. Check https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all . The all() takes an iterable and returns a boolean value.

Comment: @ShoryaSharma There are various third party data types that have an ``all`` *method*. This is unrelated to the builtin ``all`` *function*.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I understand that the solution here is to not use list.all() in the first place.  I thought he needed the built in all() operator.

Comment: Sorry for late Reply, But if i remove `.all()` then it will only check **if one of the `book name` is in the existing names,**, And `If every name in the form is new then it will show error`, BUT `if one of the four name is in existing name then it will not show the error`

Comment: You all are right, It was working fine ( as i mentioned ) But i want to check every single `name` And if one of the name is not in existingNames then show error, And If i remove **.all()** then if there are 5 names in the form and 4 are new and one is old then it will save the post, will not shoew the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the usual mistake of having a loop to check if everything fulfils some requirement, but acting immediately when encountering the first element which meets the requirement.

So

> ```
> for inputTag in names: # removed the all(), inputTag is a single one at a time
>   if inputTag in ExistingNames:
>     form.save()
>     return redirect('blogs')
>   else:
>     messages.error(
>       request, 'You cannot add new name.')
> ```

should act after the loop instead, storing the success/fail in a variable:

```
everythingisfine = True              # the new variable

for inputTag in names:               # removed the all()
  if inputTag not in ExistingNames:
    everythingisfine = False
    break                            # if one failed, no need to check the rest

if everythingisfine:                 # checking the new variable, after the loop
  form.save()
  return redirect('blogs')
else:
  messages.error(
    request, 'You cannot add new name.')
```

but, you are right about `all()` being a thing, it can make the construct much shorter:

```
everythingisfine = all(inputTag in ExistingNames for inputTag in names)

if everythingisfine:                 # checking the new variable, after the loop
  form.save()
  return redirect('blogs')
else:
  messages.error(
    request, 'You cannot add new name.')
```

Comment: Thank You Very much, It Worked.
But :- Can you explain a bit about `all(inputTags in ExistingNames` , And what's its doing ?

Comment: @Van renamed `inputTags` to `inputTag`, it is a single tag at a time. This way it may be more readable, the `inputTag in ExistingNames` is the same check you had in the original code: checks if `inputTag` (a single element) is in something, like a list here. And the second part `for inputTag in names` is the loop itself. The result of this is going to be a list (actually, generator) of `True` and `False` elements, depending on the given tag was/wasn't in `ExistingNames`. Then `all()` checks if everything is `True` in this list, stopping at the first `False`, just like the loop+`break` would.

Comment: Similarly there is an `any()` function which checks if there is at least one `True`-ish element in some iterable.